# Can NOT handle the reserver keyword "Key" in DyanmoDB command line

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to execute one query against the DynamoDB. The command line is as below:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name History
  --key-condition-expression "#k = :v1" --expression-attribute-names '{"#k":"Key"}' --expression-attribute-values file://query.json
```

Json file:

```
 { ":v1": { "S":"cef50df4-b063-cebb-e0c0-08d651599ab7"} }
```

For my talbe "History", it has the hashkey of column "Key". When I execute this command line, it always tells me that:

> Error parsing parameter '--expression-attribute-names': Expected: '=',
>   received: ''' for input: '{#k:Key}'

Can someone tell me how to correct it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem in your JSON fromate '{"#k":"Key"}'`

Please change `--expression-attribute-names '{"#k":"Key"}'`  to

`--expression-attribute-names '{\"#k\":\"Key\"}'` and try

reference Link: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2298